# Textbox doesn't accept drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, caliburn.micro

I have a `TextBox` that is defined as follows:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" x:Name="XmlFilePathName" 
    AllowDrop="True" 
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event Drop] = [Action XmlDropped($eventargs)]"/>
```

In my viewmodel I have:

```
public void XmlDropped(DragEventArgs e)
{

}
```

When I run the application and try to drop a file into the text box, it doesn't allow me to and the `XmlDropped` method is not called.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: You *must* implement the DragEnter event.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give more information? why should I implement this and what I should do in this event?

Comment: Refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263710/caliburn-micro-drag-drop-of-a-file-in-a-wpf